# How to make WordPress Elementor only display the content's excerpt in post preview's excerpt instead of the post title and date too?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor, custom-wordpress-pages

WordPress Elementor has a posts preview card where you can select which post information you want to appear in this preview. I've chosen the featured image, post title, author, publication date, and an excerpt of the post's text, containing the first 50 words. The issue is that in this post excerpt, it includes all the first words present on the post page, not just the actual content text's. Consequently, it ends up incorporating the title, author, and publication date into the excerpt, whereas I'd like it to display only the post's content text.

In the post page, I have the elements Post Title, Post Meta and Post Thumbnail, all from the plugin Royal Elementor Addons, and then Text, from regular elementor.

This is the PHP code I tried to use in functions.php, but it only displayed the first few words anyway:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 50; 
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );

function custom_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'custom_excerpt_more' );

function custom_excerpt( $excerpt ) {
    global $post;

    if ( $post->post_type === 'post' ) {
        $content = $post->post_content;

        $text = wp_strip_all_tags( $content );

        $excerpt = mb_substr( $text, 0, 50 ); 
    }

    return $excerpt;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'custom_excerpt' );

remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

Why is it not working?
Appreciate the help.